# Javascript - Reversing a Modal Animation

Tags: javascript, css, animation, css-animations

I have a few items on a site I'm building that `onclick` activate a [modal like this](http://codepen.io/theodore_steiner/pen/JRqBNE).

Right now the animation is a one-way in that, when you close it or click off from the modal's focus, it just disappears.  From what I've been reading, people seems to use the fadeIn/slideIn animation for one time effects, but is it possible, to reverse the animation so instead of just changing display to none, it slides back out?

Comment: While I haven't studied your code enough to know where to insert it, it's likely `animation-direction: reverse;` will help you here.

Comment: I would suggest you use transitions instead of animations. Define both the hidden and visible css rules to work under a class name, like "hidden" and toggle the class name. To animate, set a css transition property to the css attributes that you are changing.

Comment: @mikepa88 I think that's what I might end up doing after all.  Thanks for all the help to both of you

Comment: It's almost always better to use transitions. Animations are only necessary when you want to make something more complicated and with several steps , or auto repeating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#modal{bottom: 0; opacity: 1; transition: bottom 400ms, opacity 400ms; }
#modal.hidden{bottom: -300px; opacity: 0}
```

Then in button click event:

```
$("#modal").addClass("hidden")
```

On close event:

```
$("#modal").removeClass("hidden")
```

If you need pure javascript, it would be a bit more code but essentially that's it

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you've structured your code, you can approach this in a few ways:

- Make use of the `animation-direction: reverse;` CSS property
- Use a Javascript framework (like jQuery) that enables manipulation of DOM elements (with jQuery you could do something like: `$('element').slideIn();` to show the modal and `$('element').slideOut();` to hide the modal).
- Use CSS classes and apply / unapply them with Javascript (the option I'd recommend, and have given an example below):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.open').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if ($('.modal').hasClass('hide')) {
      $('.modal').removeClass('hide');
    }
    $('.modal').addClass('show');
  });

  $('.close').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('.modal').addClass('hide');

    if ($('.modal').hasClass('show')) {
      $('.modal').removeClass('show');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  left: -305px;
  z-index: 999;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.modal.show {
  left: 150px;
}
.modal.hide {
  left: -305px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Click <a href="#" class="open">here</a> to open modal</p>

<div class="modal">
  <p>This is a modal window.</p>
  <p>Click <a href="#" class="close">here</a> to close</p>
</div>
```

Please note that this example is only there to illustrate a proof of concept - you'll need to tidy it yourself :)